# Create Wordpress plugin page, similar to posts page

Tags: wordpress

My plugin have specific information in itself table.
I want this information to be loaded at similar wordpress posts page.

how can i to do this ?

Comment: Is there a function or class for this issue?
That I could read and display my table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or follow this for getting same table structure like post page in your plugin

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/native-admin-tables-wordpress/

http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/